# Powershell: a simple script to take a list of commands and append the same cmdlet every time

Tags: powershell, scripting, shell-scripting, powershell-v4.0

I have a list of commands I run in a script like this

```
Some-Cmdlet -someswitch | Outfile -filepath .\somefile.txt -append
Another-Cmdlet -someswitch | Out-File -filepath .\somefile.txt -append
Hello-Cmdlet -someswitch | Out-File -filepath .\somefile.txt -append
Banana-Cmdlet -someswitch | Out-File -filepath .\somefile.txt -append
```

It is actually a long list of commands creating this `somefile.txt`.

If I have to change the location or name of `somefile.txt`, I have to edit every line one by one.  I'd like to clean up the script for maintainability, so what I'd like is something like this:

For the following list of commands:

```
Some-Cmdlet -someswitch
Another-Cmdlet -someswitch
Hello-Cmdlet -someswitch
Banana-Cmdlet -someswitch
```

Always add this to the command:

```
 | Outfile -filepath .\somefile.txt -append
```

That way I only have to edit the script in one place if `somefile.txt` path or name needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to save you respecifying the same file name each time is just to save the file name in a variable, and then reference that variable on each line, like this:

```
$FileName = .\somefile.txt

Some-Cmdlet -someswitch | Outfile -filepath $FileName -append
Another-Cmdlet -someswitch | Out-File -filepath $FileName -append
Hello-Cmdlet -someswitch | Out-File -filepath $FileName -append
Banana-Cmdlet -someswitch | Out-File -filepath $FileName -append
```

Comment: Cool, thanks.  In another question someone just turned me on to the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet, which might even work better for me!